# Odd LINQ/EF Behavior when Grouping by DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, sql-server-ce

I have a bit of code that I've been using for months without problem and suddenly today I get a datetime overflow error.

The original code looks like this

```
var payments = (from p in context.Payments
                where p.PaymentType == "Direct"
                   && p.ExportFile == null
                group p by new { p.Customer, p.DebtorID, p.ReceiptNumber, p.PaymentDate } into g
                select new
                       {
                          g.Key.Customer,
                          g.Key.DebtorID,
                          amount = g.Sum(b => b.Amount) * -1,
                          ReceiptNumber = g.Key.ReceiptNumber ?? default(long),
                          PaymentDate = g.Key.PaymentDate != null ?  (DateTime)g.Key.PaymentDate : DateTime.MinValue
                       }).ToList();
```

Whats odd is, in this particular instance, the code is only selecting one row of data which looks like this:

```
ID  CUSTOMER    DEBTORID    AMOUNT  RECEIPTNUMBER   EXPORTFILE  PAYMENTTYPE PAYMENTDATE
99  183245      672         5       419             NULL        Direct      2015-06-10 00:00:00.000
```

Pretty straight forward. Nothing wrong with the date.

Stranger still, if I make the select without the grouping, it works fine.

```
var payments = (from p in context.Payments
        where p.PaymentType == "Direct"
        && p.ExportFile == null
        select new
        {
            p.Customer,
            p.DebtorID,
            p.Amount,
            p.ReceiptNumber,
            PaymentDate = (DateTime)p.PaymentDate
        }).ToList();
```

So, what gives? Like I said, the code normally works fine which leads me to believe there's something wrong with the data. But the data looks fine as well. It may be relevant that I'm retrieving my data from a SQL Server CE database. Maybe not.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: What is the type of `p.PaymentDate`?

Comment: In the database it's a datetime which also accepts null, so in C#, it's a DateTime? which is why I need to cast it to DateTime. Later on, I assign the value as a property of an object which only accepts DateTime.

Comment: Maybe it is an underflow and there is some problem with `DateTime.MinValue`. Just for the test replace it with `DateTime.UtcNow` and check if the error is gone. Then you'll have the least the reason in your code (but I couldn't explain the cause).

Comment: Interesting. SQLCE doesn't understand UtcNow, but DateTime.Now worked fine. I also tried DateTime.MaxValue which failed the same as MinValue.

In the end, I've decided to move the null checking to later in the code when I actually use the values.

Answer (score 0):

After a good tip from Oliver, I found this: [An overflow occurred while converting to datetime using EF4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730859/an-overflow-occurred-while-converting-to-datetime-using-ef4)

Turns out that .Net DateTime.MinValue is outside of the range of possible values for a SQL CE DateTime. Logically, I wouldn't expect this to be a problem because 1) I'm not trying to save the value back to the database 2) the value I've pulled from the database isn't null anyway, so the MinValue shouldn't come into play, and 3) this bit of code has worked up until just recently.  Oh, well, what's logic got to do with it?

Thanks, guys.