# Unable to add data into database MVC 5 code first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6 with code first approach. I have 3 model classes
User,country and city. I am trying to add user to database but unable to do it.
Here is my user class.

```
 public class User
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public int cityId { get; set; }
        public String firstName { get; set; }
        public String lastName { get; set; }
        public String gender { get; set; }
        public String email { get; set; }
        public String password { get; set; }
        public String photo { get; set; }
        public DateTime joinDate { get; set; }

        //public City city { get; set; }
        //public Country country { get; set; }
        public virtual City city { get; set; }
        private String FullName
        {
            get { return firstName + lastName; }
        }

    }
```

Controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(User user)
    {

        User reg = new User() { 
            cityId = 2,
            firstName = "U",
            lastName = "v",
            email = "u33@gmail.com",
            password = "123",
            gender = "Male",
            photo = "asd",
        };

        try
        {
            db.Users.Add(reg);
            db.SaveChanges();
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return View("Index","Home");
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
           // return View("Register", user);
        }
       // return View("Register", user);
    }
```

it goes to catch statement and does not add into database.

Catch Error

```
Exception:Thrown: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." (System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException)
A System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException was thrown: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
Time: 10/21/2015 5:25:41 PM
Thread:Worker Thread[5576]
```

[image]

Comment: What's the catched `Exception`?

Comment: Exception:Thrown: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." (System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException)
A System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException was thrown: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
Time: 10/21/2015 5:25:41 PM
Thread:Worker Thread[5576]

Comment: And what does say the inner Exception..?

Comment: Where can I find inner exception ?

Comment: Depending on how you get the Exception, but the inner Exception is a property of the Exception, so you can get it by a watch or in code by `e.InnerException` (where e is your Exception)

Comment: Could be you need to supply joinDate or make it nullable (DateTime?)

Comment: @ZwoRmi please check the screen shot.

Comment: @SteveGreene it is automatically picking the date.

Comment: @Umerm "Automatically picking"--as in not using `default(DateTime)`? You have it being defined in the User ctor? Otherwise, SQL doesn't understand `00-00-0000 00:00:00`, and you'll need to specify [`SqlDateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730859/an-overflow-occurred-while-converting-to-datetime-using-ef4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DateTime` is a value type you need to use a `Nullable<DateTime>` (or `DateTime?`) when you do not want to set it because the `DateTime.MinValue` (default value of a DateTime) is not in the range of acceptable values of many Sql DB DateTime field.

Fix :

```
public class User
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public int cityId { get; set; }
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public String gender { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
    public String photo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? joinDate { get; set; }

    //public City city { get; set; }
    //public Country country { get; set; }
    public virtual City city { get; set; }
    private String FullName
    {
        get { return firstName + lastName; }
    }
}
```

Th second solution is to assign a value to the `joinDate` when you create the `Person`